# Sony VAIO laptop Realtek High Definition Audio driver making buzzing sound

Tags: windows-vista, drivers, microphone, noise

When I Skype or voice chat with anyone, using any voice chat program, they say they can a hear a ring or buzzing coming from my microphone. I sometimes can fix the ring by changing the settings in my control panel, but then my voice starts sounding like a chipmunk (though the ringing leaves). I'm attributing this problem to a bad driver, so I'm wondering if anyone here knows how I could fix this issue; installing a new driver, updating my existing driver, etc?

My computer is a Sony VAIO VGN-FW351J running Windows Vista. The microphone driver that I'm using is Realtek High Definition Audio 6.0.1.6015.

Comment: Might just be line noise. A PC is filled with high-voltage circuits, and an onboard sound chip generally doesn't filter it out, in my experience. With my headphones on, I can hear noises when hard drives spin up. I used to record music direct to HD on an IBM Thinkpad, and I could discern a high-pitched chirp every now and then from the drive itself.

Comment: @IanAtkin What can I do?

Comment: Start by keeping your microphone as far from the laptop as possible. Don't let the cord cross over any power cords. Other than that, ask Sony to design better gear. :)

Comment: The microphone is built into the laptop. :\

Comment: In that case, I would invest in a headset, or if you have ear buds that you use with a cellphone, etc. The inbuilt microphone is susceptible to the many radio frequencies going back and forth inside your laptop.